# По поводу потока и завершения AsynkTask

Tags: java, android

Всем привет) У меня такая задача: С активности я запускаю подгрузку одного JSON-чика по кнопке через AsynkTask. Мне нужно запустить прогрессбар, сделать, наверное `progressBar.setCanceble(false);` до тех пор, пока не произойдет загрузка (удачно). После удачной загрузки должна запуститься активность, которая распарсенные значения уже сделает, так как я хочу, но как это сделать, я нзаю.

Вопрос: где инициализировать - `new ParseTask().execute();`, чтобы запустить его как бы сказать... Наверное, в отдельном потоке. Причем, чтобы ничего остального не включалось, понимаете о чем я?. Например, сканер устройств маяков.

Comment: Вопрос непонятен. `new ParseTask().execute();` - запустит метод `doInBackground()` в отдельном потоке.

Comment: Понимаете, запускать-то запускает, и даже данные возвращает. Но не сразу. Мне необходимо работать с получаемыми данными. Когда я это не знал, посыпались ошибки, начал исправлять и понял что код после инициаоищации выполняется быстрее, чем doInBackground. В некоторых моментах приходится делать костыли и ждать, пока этот джейсон придет. Но я бы хотел работать сразу после его загрузки. Тогда мой проект не упадет. Или попробовать сделать загрузку в отдельном классе или даже экране? P.s. прокоментирую еще, что не ясно

Comment: В AsynkTask есть метод `onPostExecute()` именно в нём надо реагировать на приход данных. Исполнять код, требующий данных сразу после вызова `new ParseTask().execute();` невозможно. Совсем. Вам надо так писать логику чтобы учитывать это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Действительно, после исполнения строчки

```
new NetworkClass((ScanningActivity) mContext).execute();
```

запускается метод `doInBackground()` в отдельном потоке.

В `NetworkClass`, унаследованном от `AsynkTask`, были добавлена возможность запуска прогресс-бара, который находится в `ScanningActivity` со специальным конструктором, и некая переменная типа `Boolean`, которая будет разрешать исполнение нужного мне участка кода в основной `Activity` после загрузки данных:

```
public NetworkClass(ScanningActivity scanningActivity) {
    this.scanningActivity = scanningActivity;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    this.scanningActivity.showProgress();
}
....

@Override
public void onPostExecute(String strJson) {
    super.onPostExecute(strJson);
    ...
    this.scanningActivity.hideProgress();
    ScanningActivity.checking = true;
}
```

Вопрос закрыт. Как показали тесты, это решает мою проблему. Спасибо за участие в обсуждениях ЮриюСПБ.